# Which branches are missing in my jacoco test report?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jacoco

I have generated a jacoco test report and three if statements indicate that 1 of 2 branches are missing.

Which cases am I missing here?

- `if (data.getId() == Data.ID) {`
- `if (data.getUser().equals(user))`
- `else if (data instanceof DataXY) {`

All statements are highlighted in yellow and say: "1 of 2 branches missed." And the bodies are marked in green on all of them.
In the first statement, the code in the else is also marked in green, so I'm a little confused about what should be missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without code and the coloring. However, as these are simple binary conditions, there is always just the "other case" missing. You can see that in the instructions in the body of the `if`. If these instructions are green, you are missing the `else` case (your test cases have to cover the opposite of the conditions). For example, there needs to be a test case where `data.getId() == Data.ID` and another one where `data.getId() != Data.ID`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an idea for the third statement? There are a bunch of else if (data instanceof ..) statements in the code and I figured out that the last one is always highlighted. Even if I swap them.

Comment: The ```else``` if is just another ```if``` as the only statement in the outer ```else``` block. To better understand the line highlighting of the coverage you can temporarily put the if into the next line.

Comment: In the third case you are probably missing a test case where ```data``` is not an instance of ```DataXY```, which is the ```else``` branch of the ```else if````, or at least a test cases where none of the other cases matches.